# May I write"...they been so kind and arranged "?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm constructing a sentence which right now looks like this

> We all know it is a long way to their nearest office, but they have
>   been so kind and arranged for them to come to us.

Is this the correct use of "been so kind" and is the sentence correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual construction is "to be so kind *as to* do something". In your example it would be:

> We all know it is a long way to their nearest office, but they have
>   been so kind as to arrange for them to come to us.

This construction seems a little odd at first, but as @FumbleFingers says below, it means (approximately) *their kindness was so great that it **caused, enabled** them to help* (i.e. - ***so*** = to such an extent).

Comment: The "justification" for *He was so kind **as** to help* as an alternative to *He was so kind to help* is that the former means (approximately) *his kindness was so great that it **caused, enabled** him to help* (i.e. - ***so** = to such an extent*), whereas *He was so kind to help* means (again, approximately) *The fact of him helping was so kind* (i.e. - ***so** = very*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks - I'll work that into my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Please do. Perhaps you'll be able to find a clearer way of expressing the distinction when not constrained by the capacity of a comment box. I think it does turn on the different *syntactic* structures appropriate to these two different *semantic* aspects of the word ***so***.

Comment: I think it's more appropriate if we say .....have been so kind that they arranged....... The use of so kind as to do something is more formal.

Comment: Either way fixes the original problem, that the "and" divorces "kind" from "arranged", as if the kindness consisted of _something else_.